# Java xml binding with JAXB: Marshaling content from a field into the root element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, annotations, xml-binding

i have a class like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
@XmlRootElement(name="someClass")
public class SomeClass implements Serializable {
    [...]
    @XmlElement(name="field")
    public String getSomeField() {
        return field;
    }
    [...]
}
```

The resulting XML after marshaling is, rightfully:

```
<someClass>
    <field>blablacontent</field>
</someClass>
```

I now want the content of "field" be the content of the someClass element directly, like this:

```
<someClass>
    blablacontent
</someClass>
```

I've looked around a lot what the annotations can do, i didn't find anything. Is this not possible ? Thanks very much for any advice !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no other `@XmlElement` annotated properties in your class, you can use [`@XmlValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlValue.html).

Comment: Aiiii, damn! It works ! Thank you very very much! Have a wonderful Christmas :).

Comment: @user3126321 You're welcome and you too! Consider accepting the answer unless there's anything else.

Comment: yup, done, had to wait until the timer expired. Can't upvote yet, not enoug rep :|